# Throwing an exception from a constructor - Core Dumped

Tags: c++, coredump

This is the Code that I execute:

```
B::B(Ptr* myPtr)
    : A( myPtr!=nullptr ? myPtr->someFunction()
                        : throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid_argument") )
    , localPtr_(myPtr)
{}
```

So, my class is constructed taking a pointer as an argument. If this pointer is nullptr I want to throw an Invalid Argument exception.

In the main I have:

```
A* myAobject = new B(nullptr);
```

So, what I expect is that the compiler throws the exception and then invokes the destructors of the objects created.

But I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  Invalid_argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And, if I try: gdb ./main core.main 
I get:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fe14f81bcc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at     ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or   directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-    gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
```

I don't understand why... Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the exception:

```
try
{
    A* myAobject = new B(nullptr);
}
catch (std::invalid_argument& e)
{
    // do something, exception was thrown...
}
```

Note that `A` destructor will not be called in this case, as the object was actually never fully created. Test it here: http://cpp.sh/7fmr

It would be unsafe to have the destructor be called, see this example:

```
class B
{
public:
    B( bool param ) : m_b1( (param) ? new int() : throw std::runtime_error("")
    {
        m_b2 = new int();
    }
    ~B()
    {
        delete m_b1;
        delete m_b2;
    }
};
```

If destructor gets called while constructor thrown the exception, `m_b2` remains uninitalized, deleting it from destructor will seg fault.

Comment: Am I sure that the objects created were destructed? Apparently, the destructors aren't invoked...

Comment: @aky - The objects were never fully constructed, because of the exception. So there is no object to destruct.

Comment: One more reason for user code not to use `new`/`delete`